# How do i stop a div float over the other?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

in the following code i have some devexpress drop down controls and a bootstrap panel with a devexpress DateNavigator (a calendar control) control in it. i have used bootstrap grids to make this responsive. all controls becomes responsive except for the calendar.

i have reduced the code so its more readable

```
<style>
    .test {width: 225px !important;}
    .timezonecss-class {height:30px !important;}

</style>
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@model CareHere.WebUI.Scheduler.Models.SchedulerDataObject

@*dont add any grid classes to the row class*@
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;width:100%"> @*padding-left:4px;padding-top:5px;padding-right:4px;*@
    @*<div class="col-sm-12" style="border:1px solid green;">*@   @*padding:0px;width:800px;">*@
        <div class='form-group left col-sm-4' style="border:0px solid blue;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;width:300px;margin-left:0px;">
            <label class="form-group" for="timeZoneEdit">Time Zone</label>

            @Html.DevExpress().TimeZoneEdit(
                settings =>
                {
                    settings.Name = "timeZoneEdit";
                    settings.SchedulerName = "scheduler";
                    settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                    settings.Height = Unit.Percentage(300);
                    //settings.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("font-weight", "large");
                    settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "timezonecss-class";
                    //settings.Width = 300;
                }).GetHtml()
        </div>

        <div class='form-group right col-sm-4' style="border:0px solid blue;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;width:228px;margin-left:2px;">
            <label for="timeZoneEdit">Select Clinic</label>
            @Html.Partial("_ClinicDropDownPartial", Model.Facility)
        </div>

        <div class='form-group right col-sm-4' style="border:0px solid yellow;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;width:228px;margin-left:1px;">
            <label for="timeZoneEdit">Select Provider</label>
            @{
                ViewBag.Resources = Model.Resources;
            }

            @Html.Partial("_ProviderDropDownPartial", Model.Provider)
        </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" style="border:1px solid black;padding:0px;width:120%;">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;padding:0px;">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid green;padding:0px;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" style="border:0px;width:100%;margin:0px;" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <span style="float:left;">Calendar</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" style="float:right"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div id="demo" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="border:1px solid orange;padding:0px;width:100%;">
                    <div class="panel-body" style="width:100%;">
                        @Html.DevExpress().DateNavigator(Html.GetSchedulerSettings()).Bind(Model.Appointments, Model.Resources).GetHtml()
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @*
    <div class="panel-group col-sm-5" id="accordion" style="border:1px solid black;padding:0px;">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-5" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;padding:0px;">
            <div class="panel-heading col-sm-5" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid green;padding:0px;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info col-sm-5" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" style="border:0px;width:100%;margin:0px;" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <span style="float:left;">Calendar</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" style="float:right"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="demo" class="panel-collapse collapse col-sm-5" style="border:1px solid orange;padding:0px;width:100%;">
                <div class="panel-body col-sm-5" style="width:100%;">
                    @Html.DevExpress().DateNavigator(Html.GetSchedulerSettings()).Bind(Model.Appointments, Model.Resources).GetHtml()
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>*@

    </div>

<div class="row" style="padding:0px;border:0px solid black;position:relative;"id="sp1">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:5px;border:0px solid black">
        @Html.Partial("SchedulerPartial", Model)
    </div>
</div>
```

two issues i have:

1. when browser size shrinks the div where the calendar is sort of goes float over the other divs as seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/gecx1YsKyr4). How do i stop this and place that calendar div at the bottom of the controls (just like other dropdown controls) [in this image it shows how it should look like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By096Igzva8NMkFuS3dJblgxZ00/view?usp=sharing)
2. How do make the calendar move to to bottom (when browser shrinks in size) after all other dropdown moved. i meant by this is the calendar must move only after all other dropdowns moved